# MySQL multiply a row by a variable

Tags: mysql

I am trying to multiply a row by a variable (calculated amount):

```
double servingsMultiplier = 1;
double servingSizeMultiplier = 1;
```

Calculate the values for "servingsMultiplier" and "servingSizeMultiplier".

```
  String selectQry5 = ("SELECT ci_id, cr_id, ci_ingedient, (ci_amount*servingsMultiplier) AS ci_amount, " + 
                " (ci_unit*servingSizeMultiplier) AS ci_unit " +
            " FROM at_cat_ingredient " + 
            " WHERE cr_id = ? " +
            " ORDER BY ci_ingedient;");
```

The above works when I use a constant (e.g., 2); however, not when I use a variable. I get the error message:

> "SQLException in recipePDF:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'servingsMultiplier' in 'field list'.

Comment: This is some kind of application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An identifier like `servingsMultiplier` inside the sql statement is not recognized as the value of the variable but as a column name, which of course does not exist.
Use `?` placeholders for `servingsMultiplier` and `servingSizeMultiplier` in the statement and pass their values just like you pass the parameter in the `WHERE` clause:

```
String selectQry5 = 
    "SELECT ci_id, cr_id, ci_ingedient, " + 
    "(ci_amount * ?) AS ci_amount, " + 
    "(ci_unit * ?) AS ci_unit " +
    "FROM at_cat_ingredient " + 
    "WHERE cr_id = ? " +
    "ORDER BY ci_ingedient;";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use mysql variables, then add `@` before variable name.

```
SELECT ci_id, cr_id, ci_ingedient, (ci_amount*@servingsMultiplier) AS ci_amount,
(ci_unit*@servingSizeMultiplier) AS ci_unit
FROM at_cat_ingredient 
WHERE cr_id = @id
ORDER BY ci_ingedient;
```